# Magento how to remove specific widgets in admin, so that client only sees relevant widgets

Tags: magento, widget, admin, backend

By default, Magento shows different widget types as options in the backend, such as 'Cms Page Link' and 'Catalog Category Link'. However, I want to provide my client only with the theme's relevant widgets, so I want to be able to remove some widgets, at least as an admin option.

The options for the backend are set via the respective core modules /etc/widget.xml. What is the best way to override this, without a core hack?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume you need restrict admin panel access to your client. Or is it something that is related to frontend ??

Answer (score 0):

@Daco

Magento has features to implement the above. It is achieved with the help of "ROLES" and "USERS" in the system tab of magento admin panel.

**Solution**

- Create a role for your client "client_xyz" by going to
  System->Permission->Roles.

[image]

- Add Resources to the role, these resources are the links that you
  would like to restrict the users upon or grant them permissions.

[image]

- After creating the roles and resources, create a user to be given to the client. The Users can be created under System->Permissions->Users.
- Create the users assign the roles that are already created. And now when the users login using this newly created credentials. They will only see what is granted by the Admin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you can't disable specific widgets, only all widgets. So this won't work.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that we can disable specific features .. for example if you need you can just show manage catalog products under Sales section and remove others ? Did you give it a try ?

Comment: Sure, but I do not want to disable the widgets functionality as a whole, only some widgets. And that's not possible in the way you described.